# I just installed SSMS 2016 and it has an odd low-resolution feel to it. SSMS 2012, on my PC, still looks normal. Any ideas?

Tags: ssms, ssms-2014, ssms-2016

I just installed SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2016, started it, and it has an odd low-resolution feel to it.  Dialog heading are slightly blurry, and things just don't look like previous versions of SSMS.  For example, SSMS 2012 still looks normal when I start it.

Any ideas?

---

Edit: I just noticed the downvotes. Sorry, didn't mean to offend anyone and I can modify this post if needed (just tell me what I'm doing wrong). In case anyone is wondering, I have googled this issue extensively, but to no avail.

Comment: `I have googled this issue extensively` - first google hit for me was [SSMS Does not display properly in high DPI](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/764009/ssms-does-not-display-properly-in-high-dpi). The fifth was [SSMS is starting to look better](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/ssms-looks-better/).

Comment: Screenshots would work wonders. We can't help you with a feeling, but maybe we can help you with facts. Downvotes doesn't mean that people were offended, they just didn't think your question was particularly good. So give us some more things to work with, like screenshots of SSMS 2012 and 2016, perhaps someone has seen the issue when they see it.

Comment: Also, what is the resolution and font scaling factor of your current setup? Like @GSerg has commented, it may just be that they blundered with the high-dpi support in the new version. If you're running >100% UI scaling factor on a high-dpi monitor, this may explain the issue. But again, screenshots would work wonders.

Comment: None of the pages I found on Google offered a good solution.  Modifying the registry on an important application like SSMS (it's very important to me) is off the table.  My assumption was that because SSMS 2012 still looks fine on my PC, then SSMS 2016 would have some easy way to make it look fine as well.  The newer version should be able to render just as well as the older version, right?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just biting the bullet and modifying the registry as outlined here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/ssms-highdpi-support/

This resolved the issue in SSMS 2016.